# SideNav bar into a hamburger

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidenav

I'm trying to get a sidenav to turn into a hamburger when viewed for example on a smaller device. This is what I currently have and thanks in advance:

```
<!-- Side navigation -->
<div class="sidenav>
    <h2 class="p auto auto"> 
        <i class="fas fa-utensils"> </i> 
        FOOD 4 YOU
    </h2>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Recipes</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can do this by using [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) , just put your hamburger element inside nav , but give it a `display:none` then in Media query , inside `max-width:992px` you can give it a `display:inline-block` so it appears